# Line Cutting off a Triangle of Given Perimeter

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, tangent-line

Through a given point inside an angle find a line cutting off a triangle of given perimeter.

From what I understand we are given some length $d$ (say via a pair of points $X,Y$ at distance $d$). Moreover we are given an angle with vertex $V$ formed by halflines $k,l,$ and a point $A$ inside it. So we are supposed to find (using a ruler and a compass) a line through $A$ intersecting $k,l$ in points $B,C$ such that the perimeter of the triangle $BCV$ (that is $|BC|+|CV|+|VB|$) equals $d$.

Any hints

Thanks

Comment: This isn't always possible, e.g. if $d < 2 |VA|$. Do you know if $d$ is sufficiently large?

Comment: No, that is what the problem states. What about if we consider a minimum perimeter?

Comment: A minimum perimeter would occur when the triangle is isosceles, that is, when the line through points $B,A,C$ is perpendicular to the line $VA$.